# How to fill an array with dictionary-type elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I need to fill an array with elements which are dictionaries. For example:

```
a = np.empty(2,2)
```

and I need to fill it in this way (which is not allowed)

```
for i in range(2):
   for j in range(2):
      a[i,j] = {'x': b[i], 'y': c[j]}
```

where `b`and `c` are other lists/arrays or columns of a dataframe.

Comment: Why would you want to use a numpy array for this? Use lists

Comment: whats your question ? add example of b and c

Comment: numpy is for numeric arrays; if you want an array of dicts use a list, if you want a database-like structure, then try pandas instead. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: You can use `object` `dtype`: `a = np.empty((2,2), object)`. As other posters suggest, the resulting `array`s functionality is limited, but if all you need is "ND indexing" you'll be fine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = np.ones(a.shape[0])
c = np.ones(a.shape[1]) * [2]

list_a = a.tolist()

for i in range(2):
   for j in range(2):
      list_a[i][j] = {'x': b[i], 'y': c[j]}

a = np.array(list_a)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[{'x': 1.0, 'y': 2.0}, {'x': 1.0, 'y': 2.0}],
       [{'x': 1.0, 'y': 2.0}, {'x': 1.0, 'y': 2.0}]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create an object dtype array, you can put anything in the slots:

```
In [9]: a = np.empty((2,2), object)                                                  
In [10]: a                                                                           
Out[10]: 
array([[None, None],                  # empty() fills with None
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
In [11]: for i in range(2): 
    ...:     for j in range(2): 
    ...:         a[i,j] = {'x':b[i], 'y':c[j]} 
    ...:                                                                             
In [12]: a                                                                           
Out[12]: 
array([[{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}],
       [{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]], dtype=object)
```

But a list comprehension works just as well

```
In [13]: [[{'x':b[i],'y':c[j]} for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)]                 
Out[13]: [[{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}], [{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]]
In [14]: np.array(_)                                                                 
Out[14]: 
array([[{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}],
       [{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]], dtype=object)
```

Or you could start with a flat list, and reshape the array:

```
In [15]: [{'x':b[i],'y':c[j]} for j in range(2) for i in range(2)]                   
Out[15]: [{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]
In [16]: np.array(_)                                                                 
Out[16]: 
array([{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3},
       {'x': 3, 'y': 3}], dtype=object)
In [18]: _.reshape(2,2)                                                              
Out[18]: 
array([[{'x': 1, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}],
       [{'x': 1, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]], dtype=object)
```

This array of dictionaries won't be any easier or faster to use than the list(s).

Alternatively we could create a structured array with 2 named fields.  Start with a list of tuples:

```
In [19]: [(b[i],c[j]) for j in range(2) for i in range(2)]                           
Out[19]: [(1, 4), (3, 4), (1, 3), (3, 3)]
In [20]: np.array(_, dtype=[('x',int),('y',int)])                                    
Out[20]: array([(1, 4), (3, 4), (1, 3), (3, 3)], dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
In [21]: _.reshape(2,2)                                                              
Out[21]: 
array([[(1, 4), (3, 4)],
       [(1, 3), (3, 3)]], dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
In [22]: _['x']                                                                      
Out[22]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [1, 3]])
```

In contrast to get all the `x` values from the 2d object array:

```
In [24]: [i['x'] for i in a.flat]                                                    
Out[24]: [1, 1, 3, 3]
```